# Matplotlib Animation: Passing variables through FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to process data within the **matplotlib.FuncAnimation** function. Anyhow, the data is iterable and I'm struggling to get the animation function in python to iterate over an external variable. In this case the Ball_1 variable.

The error this throws back is the following:
'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ball_1' referenced before assignment'

I hindsight this isn't the best way to do it. However I would like to know if it is possible?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

#         acc,vel,disp (x,y)
ball_1 = [[0,0,40],[0,0,100]]

ball_1_plot, = ax.plot(ball_1[0][2],ball_1[1][2], "o")

# 
def init_DEM():
    ball_1 = [[0,0,40],[0,0,100]]
    return ball_1_plot,

def DEM(step):
    
    TS = step/10
    
    # Ball_1
    # Contact
    grav = -9.81
    
    # Acceleration

    acc_x = 0   
    acc_y = grav  
    
    # Velocity
    vel_x = ball_1[0][1] + acc_x*TS  
    vel_y = ball_1[1][1] + acc_y*TS  
    
    # Position
    pos_x = vel_x * TS + 0.5 * acc_x * TS * TS  + ball_1[0][2]
    pos_y = vel_y * TS + 0.5 * acc_y * TS * TS  + ball_1[1][2]
    
    print(pos_x)
    # Update 
    
    ball_1 = [[acc_x,vel_x,pos_x],[acc_y,vel_y,pos_y]]
    
    # Update animation
    ball_1_plot.set_xdata(ball_1[0][2])
    ball_1_plot.set_xdata(ball_1[1][2])

    return ball_1_plot,
    
animation_run = FuncAnimation(fig,func=DEM, frames=[10,20], init_func=init_DEM, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functools.partial or a lambda function. Let's say you change your code so `ball_1` and `ball_1_plt` are not global anymore, but arguments to `DEM`. Then you call it like this:

```
from functools import partial
animation_run = FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    func=partial(DEM, ball_1=ball_1, ball_1_plot=ball_1_plot),
    frames=[10,20],
    interval=10
)
```

The references would persist between calls, so it should work, but you can not assign them within `DEM`. In other words, replace this:

```
ball_1 = [[acc_x,vel_x,pos_x],[acc_y,vel_y,pos_y]]
```

by this:

```
ball_1[0] = [acc_x,vel_x,pos_x]
ball_1[1] = [acc_y,vel_y,pos_y]
```

**Explanation**

The reason is the same reason your code is failing right now. When you assign `ball_1`, a new variable is bound. This variable is local. Your current code would run if you add the statement `global ball_1` at the top of the function. However, it is better to not use globals, but pass arguments as you suggest in your question.

This is your code without any globals, moving your top-level code into a function, and passing arguments to `DEM`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def DEM(step, ball_1, ball_1_plot):
    TS = step/10

    # Ball_1
    # Contact
    grav = -9.81

    # Acceleration
    acc_x = 0
    acc_y = grav

    # Velocity
    vel_x = ball_1[0][1] + acc_x*TS
    vel_y = ball_1[1][1] + acc_y*TS

    # Position
    pos_x = vel_x * TS + 0.5 * acc_x * TS * TS  + ball_1[0][2]
    pos_y = vel_y * TS + 0.5 * acc_y * TS * TS  + ball_1[1][2]

    # Update
    ball_1[0] = [acc_x,vel_x,pos_x]
    ball_1[1] = [acc_y,vel_y,pos_y]

    # Update animation
    ball_1_plot.set_xdata(ball_1[0][2])
    ball_1_plot.set_xdata(ball_1[1][2])

    return ball_1_plot,

def main():
    from functools import partial

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(0,100)
    ax.set_ylim(0,100)

    #         acc,vel,disp (x,y)
    ball_1 = [[0,0,40],[0,0,100]]
    ball_1_plot, = ax.plot(ball_1[0][2],ball_1[1][2], "o")

    animation_run = FuncAnimation(fig,func=partial(DEM, ball_1=ball_1, ball_1_plot=ball_1_plot), frames=[10,20], interval=10)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Excellent response thank you. I did not know about the partial class/function. Feels a bit strange running matlplotlib like a pseudo game engine. Though it definitely works. Much appreciated.